# How can I connect data from two different tables in mysql (LEFT JOIN)?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect data of two different tables from the mySQL database. This is working well, but I have one little problem:

```
 $sql = "SELECT  *  FROM person h LEFT JOIN animals o ON ( o.name = h.name);" ;
```

table `person`:

```
| id | name | age |
|----|------|-----|
| 1  | fred |  9  |   
| 2  | tom  |  8  |  
| 3  | kim  |  6  |
```

table `animals`:

```
| id | name | animal |
|----|------|--------|
| a  | fred |  cat   |   
| b  | tom  |  frog  |  
| c  | kim  |  dog   |
```

So for this loop...

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo "$row['id']"; 
echo "$row['animal']"; 
}
```

...I get the result:

```
| a  |  cat  |   
| b  |  frog |  
| c  |  dog  |
```

but the result I actually need is

```
| 1  |  cat  |   
| 2  |  frog |  
| 3  |  dog  |
```

So I need the connected data from `animals` but still keep the `id` of `person`.

Comment: your ids was letters so  you have to use numbers instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get id field from `person` not `animals`.

Fetch separate id `field`.

```
$sql = "SELECT  *, h.id as pid  FROM person h
LEFT JOIN animals o ON o.name = h.name";
```

Change in PHP:

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo $row['pid']; 
  echo $row['animal']; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the return values

```
"SELECT  person.id id, animals.animal animal FROM person h LEFT JOIN animals o ON ( o.name = h.name);"
```

This will return the 2 values you want. If you need more columns just add them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MySQL: ALIASES` for table names if you are using join queries

```
$sql = "SELECT  *, pr.id as personId  FROM person pr LEFT JOIN animals al ON al.name = pr.name";


foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo "$row['personId']"; 
echo "$row['animal']"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `id` is `ambiguous` field over here and within PHP `array having same key than last will overwrite the first` so you need to identify those key separately like as

```
SELECT h.id as pid,*  FROM person h
LEFT JOIN animals o ON o.name = h.name
```